# $K$-dimensional generalization of identity $[a_1^{n+1},a_2^{n+1}]= (a_1+a_2) [ a_1^n,a_2^n ]-a_1a_2 [a_1^{n-1}, a_2^{n-1}]$

Tags: calculus, polynomials, vectors, recurrence-relations

Is there a generalization $K$-dimensional generalization of the follows 2-dimensional identity
\begin{align}
[a_1^{n+1},a_2^{n+1}]= (a_1+a_2)   [ a_1^n,a_2^n ]-a_1a_2 [a_1^{n-1}, a_2^{n-1}]
\end{align}
where  $a_1$ and $a_2$ are positive reals.    Where $[a_1,a_2]$ is a vector of two elements.
In other words, can we similarly re-write
\begin{align}
[a_1^{n+1}, a_2^{n+1},..., a_K^{n+1}] 
\end{align}
similarly.

Also, does this identity have a name?

Comment: @nbarto  It's a vector of two elements x,y.

Answer (score 1):

When we write the $2$-dim identity as 
$$[a_1^{n+2}, a_2^{n+2}] - (a_1 + a_2)[a_1^{n+1}, a_2^{n+1}] + a_1a_2[a_1^{n}, a_2^{n}] = 0$$
then the $K$-dim generalization would be
$$\sum_{j = 0}^K (-1)^{K-j} e_j(a_1, \ldots, a_K)[a_1^{N+K-j}, \ldots, a_{K}^{N+K-j} ] = 0$$
where $e_j(a_1, \ldots, a_K)$ is the $j$th [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial).

Thus is just saying that $a_1, \ldots, a_K$ are roots of the polynomial
$$\begin{align*}
f(x) & = \sum_{j = 0}^K (-1)^{K-j} e_j(a_1, \ldots, a_K) x^{K-j} \\
& = \prod_{i=1}^K (x - a_i)
\end{align*}$$

See [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).